# WPF Extended property grid code behind customization

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid, wpf-extended-toolkit, displayname-attribute

I am using an `Extended Toolkit propertyGrid`. I need to customize it according to the user defined language preference.
From [this](http://www.broculos.net/2014/03/wpf-how-to-use-propertygrid-to-create.html#.WD6fn31F2uR) tutorial I have seen that the display name and other features can be hard-codedly changed.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ExpandableObject]
    [Category("General settings")]<-------hard coded feature change
    [DisplayName("Nome persona")]<--------hard coded feature change
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
public enum Gender { Male, Female }
```

}

But I need to do it on the runtime! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can customize those things in XAML.

Example for this class:

```
public class MyVMEntry
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Change the displaying of `Property1`:

```
<xt:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding}" AutoGenerateProperties="True">
    <xt:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
        <xt:PropertyDefinition Name="Property1" DisplayName="First Property" Category="Special"/>
    </xt:PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
</xt:PropertyGrid>
```

In XAML you can dynamically bind the values instead of using static strings if you need something runtime dependent.